# Error closing frame by clicking "x" close icon on selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am struggling to click on "x" close icon displayed on a frame. I am able perform all other operations on the frame but once i save the data on frame i need to close the frame by "x" close icon at the top of the frame. below is the html code from the frame along with the code I am trying to write to close the frame which fails with the error

```
Error
====
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector //*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '),' x-tool-close '] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '),' x-tool-close '] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.

HTML Code
=========
<div class="x-window-tc">
<div id="ext-gen180" class="x-window-header x-unselectable">
<div id="ext-gen185" class="x-tool x-tool-close"/>
<span class="x-window-header-text"/>
</div>
</div>

Webdriver Code
===========

    Driver.switchTo().frame(0); // works
    Driver.findElement(By.id("serviceButton_bottom")).click(); //// works
    Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '),' x-tool-close ']")); //Fails

Selenium finds the close icon with above mentioned xpath
```

Comment: you are finding close button but you have not applied click() method yet..

Answer (score 0):

```
 Driver.findElement(By.className('x-tool-close')).click()
```

Comment: Tried Driver.findElement(By.className("x-tool-close")).click(); but failed with error Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"x-tool-close"}
Command duration or timeout: 11.55 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html

Comment: Could you post the url?

Comment: I tried Driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.x-tool.x-tool-close")).click(); and Driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("x-tool.x-tool-close")).click; but both of them did not worked. please suggest if there is any other way of clicking on "X" close icon on frame.

Answer (score 0):

I'd the same kind of issue..
Sometimes iframe close button will have a reference in main DOM.
try switching back to main window and close.

```
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
//then write your code to close that iframe
```